# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword and createUserWithEmailAndPassword not working in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I'm developing Android application where I'm using Firebase Authentication for user login by giving email and password. I have used the basic tutorial provided by Firebase for it but after entering user ID and password I found that neither of the sign in or create account button was working.

When I debugged it, I found that control was not going to:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
```

In:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
```

Or:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
```

The code for both sign in and create account is:

```
private void createAccount(String email, String password)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "createAccount:" + email);
    if (!validateForm())
    {
        return;
    }

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
    {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                {


                        if (task.isSuccessful()) 
                       {
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } 

                       else 
                       {
                         Log.w(TAG,"createUserWithEmail:failure",task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                }
    });
}

private void signIn(String email, String password)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
    if (!validateForm())
    {
        return;
    }

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
        {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            }

            else
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }
            if (!task.isSuccessful())
            {
                mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.auth_failed);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

It just skipped the inside part in both the methods and returned nothing. I followed exactly the same way as it was in the tutorial but I'm not understanding what is exact issue. Can someone please help me where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Have you enabled firebase login with email and password in console?

Comment: Did you add the internet permission to the AndroidManifest?

Comment: @MartinDeSimone: Yes. I enabled it in the console.

Comment: @PatrixWilliams: Yes. I added internet permissions in Manifest file.

Comment: I found this in my logs 'Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.' when the control was out of the create method. Is this the reason for it?

Comment: Provide your code for sign in and create account, there must be something  you are doing wrong

Comment: @SagarRaut I have provided my code by editing my post. Please have a look.

Comment: Did you write AuthStateListener method in onCreate(). What firebase will do is like if task.isSuccessful returns true then AuthStateListener get notified first,  you must handle all the logic there i. e you can updateUI there

Answer (score 5):

do following changes in your code

declare AuthListener :

```
       // [START declare_auth_listener]
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    // [END declare_auth_listener]

   // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]
```

add listner in onStart() and onStop():

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

then add AuthStateListner method in onCreate() of your Activity,It will check for Auth status every time your activity is created:

```
// [START auth_state_listener] ,this method execute as soon as there is a change in Auth status , such as user sign in or sign out.
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user != null) {   
                    // User is signed in        
                    //redirect 
                  updateUI(user);

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                  updateUI(null);
                }

            }
        };
 // [END auth_state_listener]
```

for Sign in with email password do this..

```
        private void signIn(String email, String password)
       {
    Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
    if (!validateForm())
    {
        return;
    }

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
        {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, " Verification : signIn With Email:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    //  If sign in succeeds i.e if task.isSuccessful(); returns true then the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.


           // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
             if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        try {
                            throw task.getException();
                        } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {
                            mStatusTextView.setError("Invalid Emaild Id");
                            mStatusTextView.requestFocus();
                        } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG , "email :" + email);
                            mStatusTextView.setError("Invalid Password");
                            mStatusTextView.requestFocus();
                        } catch (FirebaseNetworkException e) {
                            showErrorToast("error_message_failed_sign_in_no_network");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                        }
                        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.login_error,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. Can I ask where you got a list of possible exceptions?

Comment: Thanks  for your  appreciation.  I got it from firebase documentation